# Adding .gitignore file to the new repo

Tags: git, github, gitignore

I just have imported my new empty *GitHub* repo using *Eclipse* *EGit*. I haven't done any other *Git* operations yet, not even added any of the project files to the *staging area*. How can i add *.gitignore* file to the repo? Would it be better to add *.gitignore* to my workspace, commit and finally push to the GitHub remote repo or just add that file in GitHub directly?

Comment: So you created a repository on GitHub. Then cloned it locally, and now you want to know if you should add your .gitignore to your local copy or to to GitHub first? I would agree with matt's answer below, unless you're working with others you should start locally then push to a remote like github.

Answer (score 1):

> Would it be better to add .gitignore to my workspace, commit and finally push to the GitHub remote repo or just add that file in GitHub directly?

There is no significant difference between those ideas. What's in the remote, no matter how it gets there, will be shared by everyone who uses the repo. And that's the goal.

---

<sub>In general, in my personal opinion, you will confuse yourself a lot less if you work locally. Learn to work with git entirely from your own machine. Editing the repo direct at the remote site is opposed to the spirit of git (and that includes pull requests, which are largely the work of the devil, even though they are essential tools for cooperative development). However, that's just an opinion.</sub>